# ASP.NET Resource not found error after moving page from one folder to another

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a ASP.NET 2.0 application with codebehind language VB. Recently I moved a page from one folder to another, compiled the application and uploaded it to web host. I am getting "The resource cannot be found." error when I try to open this page from web host. But this error does not show up in my development environment (VS 2005).

old location of the page    /usersection/masters/frmCloseTest.aspx

new location   /usersection/admin/frmCloseTest.aspx

page directive in the .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/usersection/userPanel.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
Inherits="frmCloseTest" CodeFile="frmCloseTest.aspx.vb" %>
```

Comment: are you accessing this page by redirecting to it? what is the redirect url? try typing full url in the browser address bar

Comment: No I am not using page redirection. It is plain <a href> tag and called upon click on its link.

Comment: exact url is(I rechecked, page actually exists there and all query string values are valid) http://demo.thelabman.com/usersection/admin/frmCloseTest.aspx?qsFORMID=241&qsMODID=1&qsMODNAME=Administration